# Nested filter in Elasticsearch aggregation query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am running following aggregation query with nested filter

```
GET <indexname>/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "crm.LeadStatusHistory"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "crm",
                    "query": {
                      "terms": {
                        "crm.City.keyword": [
                          "Rewa"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "crm",
                    "query": {
                      "terms": {
                        "crm.LeadID": [
                          27961
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_terms":{
              "terms": {
                "field": "crm.LeadStatusHistory.StatusID",
                "size": 1000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

-----> i have following document

```
{
        "_index" : "crm",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4478",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "crm" : [
            {
              "LeadStatusHistory" : [
                {
                  "StatusID" : 3
                },
                {
                  "StatusID" : 2
                },
                {
                  "StatusID" : 1
                }
              ],
              "LeadID" : 27961,
              "City" : "Rewa"
            },
            {
              "LeadStatusHistory" : [
                {
                  "StatusID" : 1
                },
                {
                  "StatusID" : 3
                },
                {
                  "StatusID" : 2
                }
              ],
              "LeadID" : 27959,
              "City" : "Rewa"
            }
          ]
        }
      }]
```

However in response i am getting following result

```
"aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count" : 4332,
      "agg_filter" : {
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "agg_terms" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : 1,
              "doc_count" : 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Query===> As per source document, i have 3 nested 'crm.LeadStatusHistory' documents for crm.LeadID = 27961. However, results shows for agg_filter equals to 1 instead of 3. Can you please let me know the reason for this case.

Comment: Please share your mappings.

Comment: Hi LeBigCat, please let us know specific questions as sharing mapping is not possible. I have shared source document for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Your agg_filter is on the crm.LeadStatusHistory => will target only 1 doc (LeadStatusHistory  is one doc, contaning in your case link to others doc).

i build a query who show that, and i thinck will answer to your problem. You will see the different doc_count for each aggregation.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "crm"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_LeadID": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "crm.LeadID"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_LeadStatusHistory": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "crm.LeadStatusHistory"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "home_type_name": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "crm.LeadStatusHistory.StatusID"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with this one you can count them, with a script (and filter if needed so):

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "crm"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_LeadID": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "crm.LeadID"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_LeadStatusHistory": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "crm.LeadStatusHistory"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "agg_LeadStatusHistory_sum": {
                  "sum": {
                    "script": "doc['crm.LeadStatusHistory.StatusID'].values.length"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

note: if want to get the number of nested documents, take a look to inner_hits:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-inner-hits

Answer (score 0):

I differ with the response that in 'crm.LeadStatusHistory' is one doc. I have run aggregation query on crm.LeadstatusHistory without filters.

```
GET crm/_search
{
  "_source": ["crm.LeadID","crm.LeadStatusHistory.StatusID","crm.City"], 
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "crm",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "crm.LeadID": "27961"
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "agg_statuscount": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "crm.LeadStatusHistory"
      },
          "aggs": {
            "agg_terms":{
              "terms": {
                "field": "crm.LeadStatusHistory.StatusID",
                "size": 1000
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I get following response from above query which shows 'agg_statuscount' as 6 docs without filters

```
{
  "took" : 6,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "crm",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4478",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "crm" : [
            {
              "LeadStatusHistory" : [
                {
                  "StatusID" : 3
                },
                {
                  "StatusID" : 2
                },
                {
                  "StatusID" : 1
                }
              ],
              "LeadID" : 27961,
              "City" : "Rewa"
            },
            {
              "LeadStatusHistory" : [
                {
                  "StatusID" : 1
                },
                {
                  "StatusID" : 3
                },
                {
                  "StatusID" : 2
                }
              ],
              "LeadID" : 27959,
              "City" : "Rewa"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "agg_statuscount" : {
      "doc_count" : 6,
      "agg_terms" : {
        "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
        "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : 1,
            "doc_count" : 2
          },
          {
            "key" : 2,
            "doc_count" : 2
          },
          {
            "key" : 3,
            "doc_count" : 2
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hence with crm.LeadID = 27961 in aggregation filter, i expected 3 'crm.LeadStatusHistory' docs. Currently the response is 1 as in my original question.